# Should I not include a predictor if it has a strong positive correlation with other predictors?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, model-selection

My predictor 'Waketime' has a correlation of 0.8 with my 2nd predictor 'Sleeptime' and a correlation of 0.3 with my 3rd predictor 'Bedtime'.

Should I not include this predictor in my analysis (a binomial GLM?)/not trust any of the p values of this predictor?

Comment: That is up to you and the scientific question you are asking but in general when the meaning of the predictors overlaps so much excluding one of the would seem best. If in this case Waketime+Sleeptime+Bedtime = 24 then it would definitely be best to exclude one.

Comment: @mdewey Correlation among predictors is never, *per se,* a valid reason to exclude any of them!  Because the interest concerns how much information each predictor adds (in the context of all the others) to modeling the *response* variable, no rule that ignores the response variable can be of any general value.  For instance, it is possible that your `waketime` variable is the only one of the three that has any predictive value whatsoever.

Comment: @whuber If `waketime` and `sleeptime` are (quite) correlated, wouldn't one having predictive value mean that the other has some predictive value, too?

Comment: @Dave Often that's the case, but not necessarily so.  It's easy to construct counterexamples: take *any* (reasonably large) dataset of predictor variables; generate a new nonzero variable orthogonal to them all; and add a multiple of that new variable to one of the original ones (say the first) to create a response variable.  *By construction,* if you leave out the first predictor, the regression will be useless: all coefficients will be zero.

Comment: @whuber I did say it was the meaning of the predictors which overlapped rather than them just having a high correlation per se. In the example they may well sum to a constant although we do not know that.

Comment: @mdewey And how would you operationalize "meaning"?  It plays no role in the theory, as you know; and it seems rather difficult to provide any objective, usable definition of "meaning" of any variable in a regression model.  And, assuming you could supply some definition of "meaning," how would you define "overlap" in a way that has any bearing on model selection?

Comment: As already noted, pairwise dependence has little meaning wrt multicollinearity. What has not been noted is that *partial* correlations do have meaning wrt multicollinearity. That said, there is usually little empirical motivation for excluding predictors *a priori* or in the absence of evidence as to how they perform in a multiple regression. Most software offers routines for diagnosing these issues which include, VIFs, collinearity eigenvalue indexes, etc.